# Hide formula in selected range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to hide formulas in G11 to G55. But it hides all formulas and protects the sheet4. How can I only hide and protect cell in G15:G55? Thank you.

```
Sub Loc()
    Dim c As Range
    Worksheets("sheet4").Range("G15:G55").Select

    For Each c In Selection
        If c.HasFormula = True Then
           c.Locked = True
           c.FormulaHidden = True
        End If
    Next c
    'Worksheets("sheet4").Range("G11:G55").Locked = True
    Worksheets("sheet4"").Protect Password:="111"
End Sub
```

Can following code be modified

```
Sub Locs()
    Dim c As Range, rng1, rng2 As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Unprotect Password:="111"

    Cells.Locked = False
    Cells.FormulaHidden = False

    Set rng1 = Range("G15:G55")
    Set rng2 = Range("I15:I55")

    For Each c In rng1
        If c.HasFormula = True Then
            c.Locked = True
            c.FormulaHidden = True
        End If
    Next c

    For Each c In rng2
        If c.HasFormula = True Then
            c.Locked = True
            c.FormulaHidden = True
        End If
    Next c

    Worksheets("Sheet4").Protect Password:="111"
End Sub
```

Comment: You only need one **Set** and only one loop........................`Set rng = Union(Range("G15:G55"), Range("I11:I55"))`

Comment: @Gary's Thanks...............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Loc()
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range

    Worksheets("sheet4").Unprotect Password:="111"
        Cells.Locked = False
        Cells.FormulaHidden = False
        Set rng = Range("G15:G55")

        For Each c In rng
            If c.HasFormula = True Then
                c.Locked = True
                c.FormulaHidden = True
            End If
        Next c
    Worksheets("sheet4").Protect Password:="111"
End Sub
```

This locks only the cells of interest and frees up the others.  You can change the **G15** to **G11** if you wish.

Comment: @ Gary's It is fine, I want to it to go for another range, is there easy way to modify the code,

Comment: @Kuma  It is all in the **Set** command.....you can change this to include a different range or a set of different ranges....................